# how to sort, reverse the array in the visual basic asp.net 2010,

Tags: asp.net

Here is my code but it just shows the output of save button, but not on sort and reverse button. The `MessageBox` does not display anything...?

```
Partial Class array_demo_output
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Dim s(5) As String
    Dim str As String
    Dim a As String

    Protected Sub btn_save_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn_save.Click

        s(0) = txt1.Text
        s(1) = txt2.Text
        s(2) = txt3.Text
        s(3) = txt4.Text
        s(4) = txt5.Text
        s(5) = txt6.Text

        MsgBox("THE LENGTH OF ARRAY S IS" + s.Length.ToString)

        For Each a In s
            str &= a + vbNewLine
        Next
        MsgBox(str, , "member of the array")
    End Sub

    Protected Sub btn_sort_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn_sort.Click

        System.Array.Sort(s)

        str = ""

        For Each a In s
            str &= a + vbNewLine
        Next

        MsgBox(str, , "sorted memeber of the array")
    End Sub

    Protected Sub btn_reverse_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn_reverse.Click

        System.Array.Reverse(s)
        str = ""

        For Each a In s
            str &= a + vbNewLine
        Next

        MsgBox(str, , "Reversed Member of the Array")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6tf1f0bc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1): "Each element of array must implement the `IComparable` interface to be capable of comparisons with every other element in array."

Answer (score 0):

You have defined elements of array inside Save function. If you click sort or reverse before pressing Save, the array still remains empty. Move the array initialization in a separate function form loading or something...

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize array.It's passed as Empty value while calling in sort and reverse.
Please check the following code

```
 Partial Class array_demo_output
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Dim s(5) As String
    Dim str As String
    Dim a As String
  Protected Sub btn_save_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        loadarray()

        MsgBox("THE LENGTH OF ARRAY S IS" + s.Length.ToString)

        For Each a In s
            str &= a + vbNewLine
        Next
        MsgBox(str, , "member of the array")
    End Sub

    Protected Sub btn_sort_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        loadarray
        System.Array.Sort(s)

        str = ""

        For Each a In s
            str &= a + vbNewLine
        Next

        MsgBox(str, , "sorted memeber of the array")
    End Sub

    Protected Sub btn_reverse_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        loadarray()
        System.Array.Reverse(s)
        str = ""

        For Each a In s
            str &= a + vbNewLine
        Next

        MsgBox(str, , "Reversed Member of the Array")
    End Sub
    Public Sub loadarray()
    s(0) = txt1.Text
        s(1) = txt2.Text
        s(2) = txt3.Text
        s(3) = txt4.Text
        s(4) = txt5.Text
        s(5) = txt6.Text
    End Sub
END Class
```

Answer (score 0):

You have initialized the array only in the btn_save click event. 
In the btn_reverse_Click and btn_sort_Click the array string is empty. 
So initialize the array globally.

Answer (score 0):

```
Protected Sub BtnSort_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnSort.Click
    Array.Sort(s)
    For i = 0 To s.Length - 1
        MsgBox(s(i).ToString())
    Next
End Sub
Protected Sub BtnRev_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnRev.Click
    Array.Reverse(s)
    For i = 0 To s.Length - 1
        MsgBox(s(i).ToString())
    Next
End Sub
```